# How do I create a PGP Key Revocation Certificate in Seahorse

Tags: keyrings, seahorse, certificates, pgp, openpgp

I created a PGP Key using Seahorse in Ubuntu's Passwords and Keys (13.04). To my understanding, creating a revocation certificate for the PGP key is important for a couple of reasons.

I don't see any way of creating the revocation certificate in Ubuntu. I would appreciate some direction with this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're fine with using the command line, this is easily done using [`gpg --gen-revoke`](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/c14.html#REVOCATION).

The revocation certificate is stored in `revoke.asc` (in your home directory if you do not change anything else) and you should replace `mykey` by your key id.

```
gpg --output revoke.asc --gen-revoke mykey
```

Remember to store it in a save place, for example by printing it to a QR code or something similar.

Comment: Thank you Jens. Just clarifying, only if this revoked certificate is published that my existing key becomes revoked. Is that right? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes that's right. As soon as you share that certificate (eg. by uploading it to key servers) and others update your key they will have it marked as "revoked".