# How to share the public OpenPGP key using GnuPG?

Tags: gnupg

I used GnuPG to generate a key. But looking at the GUI, I cannot tell where my public key is stored. I would like to share it with friends.

I clicked on export, this exported a name.asc file, but when I open the file in gedit it is labeled as a private key so I am assuming this is not the public key for sharing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the command line:

Run `gpg --list-keys 'your name'` to list the keys you currently have  (replacing `your name` with the name you have while setting up):

```
$ gpg --list-keys muru      
/home/muru/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
--------------------------------
pub   2048R/AD0CC9B4 2015-07-15
uid                  muru
sub   2048R/450DAD90 2015-07-15
```

Note the fingerprint of the key you want to export. The fingerprint of my public key is `AD0CC9B4`. To export it, I'll do `gpg --export` (`-a` is for ASCII armour, so that the key is in the usual base64-encoded form):

```
$ gpg -a --export AD0CC9B4
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1

mQENBFWm4zkBCADYo5ffanvwBVGMbfp3g+/RMYb41QRZXCGSUhZkU7m3BpPSoO/4
NBzD4KKAU6CTVzBmVmZoFGgK2dDIOv+ZCkB4USZM2cvvpu7I+jfaYZW7ouQ4uEYu
8xY8ugFn5ImsK4KN0OP+Iw1VBXLdvj/rEiV+gcH8QV0XhsfgczCxjS1dMV3AMD+h
# snip
Wo0X3XmrPpaHJf7MsjGmJGbHNX9ZLllyFWQPlNdu9ilLI9GMjSpJSqQ=
=l/Xm
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

You can redirect the output to a file:

```
gpg -a --export AD0CC9B4 > my-pubkey.asc
```

Then `my-pubkey.asc` should contain your ASCII-armoured public key.

The corresponding private key can be exported with:

```
gpg -a --export-secret-keys AD0CC9B4
```

The output of this command will begin with

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

Answer (score 3):

> I clicked on export, this exported a name.asc file, but when I open the file in gedit it is labeled as a private key so I am assuming this is not the public key for sharing.

This would indeed be a bad idea, as the private key should remain - private.

Your public key is stored in the GnuPG keyring (`~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg` by default). To distribute it, you have two options. Both should also be available in most graphical user interfaces, but might have different names for the commands.

1. **Exporting the key and shipping it manually**

   To export your key, use the `--export` option, which exports a given public key together with all user IDs, subkeys and certifications received. `-a`/`--ascii` enables ASCII-armoring, which is mostly a Base64-like encoding making transmission safer, while slightly increasing the file size (which is still rather small).

   ```
   gpg --ascii --export [key-id] > your-key.asc
   ```

   You can now mail or upload this file somewhere, or pass it around on another medium of your choice.
2. **Upload the key to the key server network**

   Usually, keys are distributed using the key server network. Uploading your public key is very easy using the `--send-key` command.

   ```
   gpg --send-key [key-id]
   ```

   Now others can search and receive your key by executing

   ```
   gpg --search [mail address]
   gpg --recv-key [key-id]
   ```

   Also, most OpenPGP implementations will support querying key servers for mail addresses to use in some kind, manually or automatically.

   Be aware [you can never delete OpenPGP keys from the key server network](https://askubuntu.com/a/626549/167385) (no matter who uploaded it)!